# include pdf in a tcolorbox

Tags: floats, tcolorbox, pdfpages

I am triying to include a pdf in a tcolorbox but the compiler thinks I want it behind the box. Here is a simplifed version of the code I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{sapphire}{rgb}{0.03, 0.15, 0.4}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white,colframe=sapphire,title={The pdf is suppose to be inside the box}]

\lipsum[1]

 \begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
          \includepdf[scale=.5]{file.pdf}
  \end{figure}

\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

And here is what the compiler understands:[image: The file.pdf is outside the tcolorbox]

If I add text in the box and upscale file.pdf, we clearly see the file.pdf is not only outside the box but behind it:

[image: The file.pdf is behind the tcolorbox].

I succeeded in including it as a image, but I would like it to be text.

Thank you for your help

Comment: you should not use \includepdf there, try with \includegraphics (which is used by \includepdf internally but doesn't force newpages).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you very much

Comment: @UlrikeFischer -- If this isn't duplicated somewhere else, please add an answer so it doesn't get lost.

Comment: @TYFYH Editing the question title to add “[Solved ...]” is not the way to go here. Please mark the answer as accepted as explained in [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `\includepdf` inside boxes. `\includepdf` is for full pages.

Use `\includegraphics` (which is used by `\includepdf` too) but doesn't force newpages.